In the War Scroll 17:4-9, who is "the Angel of the kingdom of Michael" that relieves the saints, and how does this shed light on Michael in Daniel?
War Scroll 17:4-9

To the God of Israel belongs all that is and shall be; He knows all
the happenings of eternity. This is the day appointed by Him for the
defeat and overthrow of the Prince of the kingdom of wickedness, and
He will send eternal relief to the company of His redeemed by the might
of the princely Angel of the kingdom of Michael. With everlasting light He will enlighten with joy the children of Israel; peace and blessing shall be with the company of God.
He will raise up the kingdom of Michael in the midst of the gods, and
the realm of Israel in the midst of all flesh. Righteousness shall
rejoice on high, and all the children of his truth shall celebrate in
eternal knowledge.
And you, the sons of His Covenant, be strong in the ordeal of God! His
mysteries shall uphold you until He moves His hand for His trials to
come to an end.

My two-fold question is, who is "the princely Angel of the kingdom of Michael", and in what way does this shed light on 2nd temple period Jewish understanding of Michael in the book of Daniel?

Is he the Lord Jesus Christ, the Son of God?

In the Community Rules scroll, he is called the "Prince of Light" and the "Angel of Truth".

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about a Biblical text.

@curiousdannii I can see why you would close this particular question since it doesn't relate directly to canonical texts. But I hope this does not mean that all questions about DSS texts are out of bounds. They can shed light on both the OT and the NT. For example if this question were phrased to help us understand "Michael" in the Book of Daniel - or even to help us understand 1st c. Judaism, there were be no reason to close it IMO.

@DanFefferman – Can you give it a shot at explaining the connection between Daniel and the War Scroll regarding Michael?

The question has been closed but  the Qumran community understood that  Daniel's prophecies would be realized in their own time. However, the group's angelogy had evolved. While Daniel names only Michael, the War Scroll (col 9) also speaks of Gabriel and Raphael, two names that enter the literature later on. In the War Scroll Michael is the leader of the sons of light against the sons of darkness. He is not the messiah, either the priestly messiah (whom the Essenes consider primary) or the royal messiah.

@curiousdannii Since the question now specifically asks how the War Scroll is related to the Book of Daniel, I voted to re-open.
