In Daniel 8-12, how can the Messiah and Michael both be our Prince?
Daniel 8:11

It became great, even as great as the Prince of the host. And the
regular burnt offering was taken away from him, and the place of his
sanctuary was overthrown.

Daniel 8:25

By his cunning he shall make deceit prosper under his hand, and in his
own mind he shall become great. Without warning he shall destroy many.
And he shall even rise up against the Prince of princes, and he shall
be broken—but by no human hand.

Daniel 9:25

Know therefore and understand that from the going out of the word to
restore and build Jerusalem to the coming of the Messiah, the Prince,
there shall be seven weeks. Then for sixty-two weeks it shall be built
again with squares and moat, but in a troubled time.

Daniel 10:13

The prince of the kingdom of Persia withstood me twenty-one days,
but Michael, foremost of chief princes, came to help me, for I was left there with the kings of Persia,

Daniel 10:21

"But I will tell you what is inscribed in the book of truth: there is
none who contends by my side against these except Michael, your
Prince."

Daniel 12:1

“At that time shall arise Michael, the great Prince who has charge of
your people. And there shall be a time of trouble, such as never has
been since there was a nation till that time. But at that time your
people shall be delivered, everyone whose name shall be found written
in the book."

From these six key passages, we learn that the Messiah is the Prince, and that Michael is our Prince. How can this be, and does this imply that we have two princes, or that the Messiah is the incarnation of Michael?

Many believe, on the basis of the evidence you present (and much else) that Michel is Messiah.

@Dottard, if this is true, then Michael is one among chief princes, the foremost among archangels, truly the firstborn son of God.

As the Divine Name Angel, Michael would have the authority to speak on God's behalf as his representative and mediator, without needing to be God himself.

If Michael is Jesus, then Michael is the Angel of the LORD, and, God Almighty.  This makes Him the Chief of the angels = "Archangel"), and Prince/commander of heavenly princes, etc.

@Dottard, I would agree that Michael is the Angel of the LORD, but I see no reason to think that the Diving Name Angel is God Almighty. An angel is not God, but a son of God, of which Michael is the firstborn Son of all creation. Because Michael carries the Divine Name, he can speak on behalf of God and carry his divinity without actually being God himself. Michael is God's vizier.

That is an interesting idea but not supported by any evidence.  I will add an answer to show this.

@Dottard, I beg to differ. Here is some supporting evidence: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://www.ministersnewcovenant.org/uploads/9/1/6/1/9161032/divine_agency_in_the_scriptures_pdf.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiQj8zEuLuKAxWQ4MkDHV1RGyYQFnoECBQQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1uv1OSzcJwarTS4AKir6XB

Note that this question is identical to In Daniel 8-12, how can the Messiah and Michael both be our Prince? - Christianity Stack Exchange.

This should be asked in Christianity.SE

That referenced paper simply begins with the assumption that Jesus is NOT God and cannot be God so the doctrine of the "Vizier" is developed (kept repeating it) to keep explaining that assumption.  Frequent repetition does not prove the point.

I'm going to give you your second upvote here. Not many people on this site are willing to make the Archangel Michael and Jesus connection. Nevertheless, it may interest you to know that I, at least, did just that, when answering the following Q: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/47745/why-doesnt-the-father-know-the-name-which-was-written/49479#49479 ... If you concur with what I wrote in response to this now linked Q., you know what to do.

@OldeEnglish – I upvoted it, great work. Was wondering what your thoughts were on this passage from the DSS War Scroll: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/99943/90486

I am not familiar with this scroll, so unfortunately (for you) have no thoughts on same. Nevertheless, I appreciate your reciprocating vote.

It's a little early in our relationship to be emailing. In the 4 1/2 years of me being a member on this site only 2 (long standing with high reputation) members have my email. With all due respect, I don't know you from Adam. You don't even have a profile of yourself ....

@OldeEnglish – It's all good, I'm a born-again Christian with a new heart. Unitarian, from the U.S., I'm very friendly and against all sin. I trust you, and I'd like to talk about some related material if you are willing.

We could go to "Chat", although it's 12:38 AM here in Colorado right now and I am about to hit the sack, so until tomorrow I guess??

@OldeEnglish – Okay, let's make a chat together.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I prefer the explanation that Michael is not the Messiah in any of these prophecies. He is Israel's protector and the leader of the heavenly host, a role that later evolved into "archangel."
Part of the confusion arises from the fact that "prince" (sar) more often means captain, chief, general, governor, keeper, lord, master, ruler, steward. Another problem is that Dan. 8-9 does not speak of Michael so we should not presume that he is referred to. Specifically:

Daniel 8:11 - No mention of Michael. The "Prince of the host" in this case is God, to whom the temple sacrifices were offered.

Daniel 8:25 - Same as above. The Prince of princes is God, who rules the entire earth.

Daniel 9:25 - Still no mention of Michael, but this particular prince is indeed an anointed leader, possibly the Messiah, but possibly a normal anointed king such as one of the Hasmoneans who came to power after the Maccabean Revolt.

Daniel 10:13 - Here Michael is finally mentioned. He is the chief of the "princes," which in this case has military connotations. This leads to the idea that he is an archangel, who fights against the guardian spirits of the Persian Empire (and later Greece).

Daniel 10:21 - "there is none who contends by my side against these except Michael, your Prince." This is apparently another reference to Michael's role as the guardian angel of Israel.

Daniel 12:1 - “At that time shall arise Michael, the great Prince who has charge of your people." Once again, Michael is the name of Israel's guardian angel, who protects them in this case against various kingdoms formerly ruled by Greece (according to the Maccabean hypothesis of Daniel's origins, a reference to the aftermath of the rule of Alexander the Great).


Conclusion. The OP asks "how can the Messiah and Michael both be our Prince?" The answer is that "prince" is only one way that the Hebrew word "sar" can be translated, and several of these passages do not refer to Michael in any case. Michael is Israel's guardian spirit, not the Messiah.

According to Matthew Poole when commenting on Dan 10:13 -

Michael: this we take to be Christ.

His name signifies, who is like God.
He is the first in dignity above all the angels, Hebrews 1:4-7, &c., called archangel, and the church’s prince, Daniel 10:21.
The chief champion of his church, helping Gabriel not as his fellow, but as his general. Thus we see what care God takes of his
church’s safety against their potent enemies, by doubling their
succours, (when he could do it, if he pleased, without means,) thereby
to consult his own glory in the world by defeating the counsels and
breaking the powers of the mightiest enemies, after he had given them
rope to do their worst.


Gill reaches the same conclusion:

Michael one of the chief Princes, came to help me; called in the New
Testament an Archangel, the Prince of angels, the Head of all
principality and power; and is no other than Christ the Son of God

The Geneva Bible also has this at Dan 10:13 -

Michael, that is, Christ Jesus the head of angels

The title "archangel" simply means "leader of angels" and is never applied to anyone except Michael. (The pseudepigrapha applies this name to a number of angels, but these are all unbiblical.) The OP's set of verses concerning the heavenly prince Michael also points in the same direction.
The name "Michael" also occurs in Rev 12:7 (pointing to Christ, see Benson's commentary) and in Jude 9.
Now, this does not make Jesus an angel, far from it as the appendix below demonstrates.  The shouted excuse that Michael peaks for the LORD does not hold water because in all cases when someone speaks on behalf the LORD or quotes the LORD (such as a prophet) they say as much.
APPENDIX - "Angel of the LORD"
The following passages make it clear that the “Angel of the LORD” is almost always, the LORD (Jehovah) Himself, probably Jesus in particular.  Gen 16:7-13, 22:11-17, 32:24-30, 48:16, Ex 3:2-6, 32:34, Num 22:22-35, Josh 5:13-15, Judg 2:1-4, 6:11-23, 13:3-23, Isa 63:9, Dan 3:25, 28, Hos 12:4, 5, Zech 3:1-7, Mal 3:1, Rev 8:3-5, 10:1-10, 18:1, 20:1-4.
A closely related phrase, “Angel of God” who is clearly God as in Gen 6:13, 8:15, 9:8, 17, 15:13, 17:3, 4, 21:12, 16-21, 35:1, 10, Ex 4:3-8, 6:2, 23:20, 21, Deut 1:6, 1 Kings 12:22, etc.  See also Acts 10:3, 4, Gal 4:14.

+1 from me, a good eisegesis. I would only ask you further for clarification as to whether a vizier can speak on behalf of who appointed him without actually being the one who appointed him?

@OneGodOneLord - "vizier" is your word not a Biblical word.  Jesus speaks on His own authority precisely because He is the LORD.

Dottard, as I see it, the term "Son of God" resonates with a heavenly angel, as they are called "sons of God" is like fashion, further offspring of God along with Christ, who is firstborn among them. In Rev. 1:1, Jesus is the Angel of God sent to give John the Revelation.

@OneGodOneLord - that is all fine, but there is only on "The Son of God" which is Jesus - the same person who is The LORD in the OT and God in the NT as I have tabulated here on numerous occasions.  See https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/74076/did-jesus-ever-pray-to-jehovah/74078#74078

Dottard, I believe in divine agency - that the Son is the authorized representative of Almighty God. In being God's agent, the Divine Name Angel, Michael, can speak on God's behalf and receive worship by God's direct enabling. He is God's vizier as Joseph was pharaoh's vizier and Aaron was Moses' vizier. They were authorized agents/viziers.

@OneGodOneLord - you may believe anything you want.  I believe in the teaching of the Bible.  Now, on BHSX, that is what is discussed - what the Bible is saying.  Therefore, If you wish to assert something, Bible evidence MUST be supplied.

Dottard – Want Bible evidence? It's everywhere. Recall that Joseph was Pharaoh's agent, and Aaron was Moses' agent. Agency has real biblical precedent and we must never forget the teaching of John 1:18 that nobody has seen God, but the Son has revealed him, as he is God's supreme agent (vizier & mediator).

The texts you have quoted from clearly distinguish between the angel of the LORD (the preincarnate Jesus) and Michael the archangel.

4 On the twenty-fourth day of the first month, as I was standing on
the bank of the great river, the Tigris, 5 I lifted up my eyes, and
behold, there was a certain man dressed in linen, with a belt of fine
gold from Uphaz around his waist. 6 His body was like beryl, his face
like the brilliance of lightning, his eyes like flaming torches, his
arms and legs like the gleam of polished bronze, and his voice like
the sound of a multitude. 7 Only I, Daniel, saw the vision; the men
with me did not see it, but a great terror fell upon them, and they
ran and hid themselves. 8 So I was left alone, gazing at this great
vision. No strength remained in me; my face grew deathly pale, and I
was powerless. 9 I heard the sound of his words, and as I listened, I
fell into a deep sleep, with my face to the ground. 10 Suddenly, a
hand touched me and set me trembling on my hands and knees. 11 He said
to me, “Daniel, you are a man who is highly precious. Consider
carefully the words that I am about to say to you. Stand up, for I
have now been sent to you.” And when he had said this to me, I stood
up trembling. 12 “Do not be afraid, Daniel,” he said, “for from the
first day that you purposed to understand and to humble yourself
before your God, your words were heard, and I have come in response to
them. 13 However, the prince of the kingdom of Persia opposed me for
twenty-one days. Then Michael, one of the chief princes, came to help
me, for I had been left there with the kings of Persia. 14 Now I have
come to explain to you what will happen to your people in the latter
days, for the vision concerns those days.” 15 While he was speaking
these words to me, I set my face toward the ground and became
speechless. 16 And suddenly one with the likeness of a man touched my
lips, and I opened my mouth and said to the one standing before me,
“My lord, because of the vision, I am overcome with anguish, and I
have no strength. 17 How can I, your servant, speak with you, my lord?
Now I have no strength, nor is any breath left in me.” 18 Again the
one with the likeness of a man touched me and strengthened me. 19 “Do
not be afraid, you who are highly precious,” he said. “Peace be with
you! Be strong now; be very strong!” As he spoke with me, I was
strengthened and said, “Speak, my lord, for you have strengthened me.”
20 “Do you know why I have come to you?” he said. “I must return at
once to fight against the prince of Persia, and when I have gone
forth, behold, the prince of Greece will come. 21 But first I will
tell you what is inscribed in the Book of Truth. Yet no one has the
courage to support me against these, except Michael your prince.
(Daniel 10)

The above text clearly presents the distinction between the mysterious man (dressed in linen, with a belt of fine gold), and Michael. Michel is a subordinate here, that assist the figure dressed in linen. They are not the same. Verse 18 (the one with the likeness of a man כְּמַרְאֵה אָדָם kemareh adam), is an obvious hyperlink to Ezekiel 1:26:

Above the expanse over their heads was the likeness of a throne with
the appearance of sapphire, and on the throne high above was a figure
like that of a man (כְּמַרְאֵה אָדָם).

The man in linen is the Prince of the host (שַׂר-הַצָּבָא) of Daniel 8:11 and the commander of the army of the LORD (שַׂר-צְבָא-יְהוָה) of Joshua 5:13-15. He is the visible manifestation of the invisible God. Michael on the other hand is only one of the host (Daniel 10:13), a subordinate.
So how can Michael be a prince/protector of the Judeans?
In Genesis 11 we have the story of the tower of Babel. As a consequence of that rebellion, God disinherited the nation and out of Abram and Sarai created a new people. A new nation established to be a rescue plan for the humanity. The first evidences of this are the table of 70 nations of Genesis 10 and the numbering of Jacob's family of 70 in Genesis 46.
Then we learn from Deuteronomy 32:8 (Septuagint and the Dead Sea Scrolls), that God left the disinherited nations under the protection of angels:

When the Most High divided the nations, when he separated the sons of
Adam, he set the bounds of the nations according to the number of the
angels of God.

But instead of protecting, the princes convinced the peoples to worship them instead of God.

19 And when you look up to the sky and see the sun, the moon and the
stars—all the heavenly array—do not be enticed into bowing down to
them and worshiping things the Lord your God has apportioned to all
the nations under heaven. 20 But as for you, the Lord took you and
brought you out of the iron-smelting furnace, out of Egypt, to be the
people of his inheritance, as you now are. (Deuteronomy 4)

The same association of angels with the stars and their role as protectors is also present in the NT.

The mystery of the seven stars that you saw in my right hand and of
the seven golden lampstands is this: The seven stars are the angels of
the seven churches, and the seven lampstands are the seven churches.
(Revelation 1:20)

This is what the princes of Persia and Greece are. Rebellious angels that became false gods of the nations they were appointed to protect.
The role of Michael as a protector of the Judeans seems to start in Ezekiel 10&11:

4 Then the glory of the Lord rose from above the cherubim and moved to
the threshold of the temple. The cloud filled the temple, and the
court was full of the radiance of the glory of the Lord. 5 The sound
of the wings of the cherubim could be heard as far away as the outer
court, like the voice of God Almighty when he speaks.  … 18 Then the
glory of the Lord departed from over the threshold of the temple and
stopped above the cherubim. 19While I watched, the cherubim spread
their wings and rose from the ground, and as they went, the wheels
went with them. They stopped at the entrance of the east gate of the
Lord’s house, and the glory of the God of Israel was above them.
(Ezekiel 10) 22 Then the cherubim, with the wheels beside them, spread
their wings, and the glory of the God of Israel was above them. 23 The
glory of the Lord went up from within the city and stopped above the
mountain east of it. (Ezekiel 11)

The role of Michael as an angel/protector of the nation started when the glory of the LORD departed from Jerusalem. Until then, God Himself was the guardian of the people.

You made this statement OneGodoneLord, "@Dottard, I would agree that Michael is the Angel of the LORD," I would love to hear how you would prove that the angel of the Lord is Michael?
Having said that I can prove that it's impossible for Michael to be the angel of the Lord. Furthermore, I can prove from the Bible (specifically the Old Testament) that the preincarnate Jesus Christ is the angel of the Lord.
You can't "assume" that the angel of the Lord is just that, an actual angel which Michael is. You also made this statement: "or that the Messiah is the incarnation of Michael?" What your doing here is committing the fallacy of a category error, or simply comparing apples and oranges. There is zero evidence that an actual angel can be the Messiah. The Messiah is a person named Jesus Christ who incarnated as a human being. Hebrews 1:1-3 confirms this as well as a ton of other verses.
To me one of the best proofs that Michael is not the angel of the Lord but rather the preincarnate Jesus Christ can be found at Genesis 22:15-17, "Then the angel of the Lord called to Abraham a second time from heaven, vs16 and said, By Myself I have sworn, DECLARES THE LORD, because you have done this thing, and have not withheld you son, your only son, vs17, indeed, I will greatly multiply your seed as the stars of the heavens and as the sand that is on the seashore; and your seed shall possess the gate of their enemies."
Please note at Genesis 16 it says, "and said." It's the angel of the Lord speaking himself and he is not speaking on behalf of God Almighty. Also note the words, "By Myself I have sworn DECLARES THE LORD, Here again the angel of the Lord is identified as "the Lord" in the verse.
At vs17 the same person doing the speaking has not changed and the angel of the Lord says, "I will greatly multiply your seed etc." Now, what backs all of this up can be found in the New Testament at Hebrews 6:13-18.
The writer of Hebrews states at vs13, "For when GOD MADE THE PROMISE to Abraham, SINCE HE COULD SWEAR BY NO ONE GREATER, HE SWORE BY HIMSELF, Vs14, "saying, I will surely bless you, and I will surely multiply you." Vs15, "And thus, having patiently waited, he obtained the promise."
At vs16, notice the writer makes a point of saying the following; "For men swear BY ONE GREATER THAN THEMSELVES. In other words in a courtroom men or women are asked by the Bailiff will say, "Do you swear to tell the truth, the whole truth, "SO HELP YOU GOD." Of course the whole point of this exercise is to demonstrate that an actual angel or angels cannot swear oaths on behalf of God, period. This means that Michael cannot be the angel of the Lord.
And as a side note, angels do swear oaths on their own. This is confirmed at Revelation 10:5-6. "And the angel whom I saw standing on the sea and on the land LIFTED up his right hand to heaven, vs6, and swore BY HIM WHO LIVES FOREVER AND EVER, who created heaven and the things in it, and the earth and the things in it. And the sea, and the things in it, that there shall be delay no longer."

Mr.Bond, in Joshua 5:14,  the Angel of the LORD has an outstretched sword and reveals himself to be the Commander of the Armies of Heaven, the role of Michael himself in Revelation 12:7 and Daniel 8:11.

OneGodOneLord . So what's your point? Obviously you failed to read  vs15 where the angel of the Lord ask Joshua to remove his sandals because he was on holy ground just like at Exodus 3:5. The other thing you did wrong was not read the context. Chapter 6:1-2 which is a continuation of the discussion with Joshua and notice what vs2 states, "And the Lord said to Joshua, "Sii I have given Jericho unto your hand, with its king and valiant warriors." And btw, you quoting Revelation 12 or Daniel 8:11 has nothing to do with what's happening with Joshua here af 5 and 6. Try again!

Mr.Bond, the ground on which he was standing was holy, because the Angel (Michael/Christ) is God's supreme vizier, the representative agent and mediator between God and men. Chest has this authority because as the firstborn Son, the Divine Name of God is within him.
